# php function re-executed after about 15 minutes

Tags: php

I have a php script which is runtime should take about 20-25 minutes, and approximately 15 minutes during execution time it simply re-executing for no apparent reason.

I gave it a token to make sure it kills the second execution before it runs again, but it's not the solution I prefer to use in the long run.

Some details about the script:

- It ignites after a socket connection (socket does not timeout nor restarting at any point of the session.)
- I gave the php script `ignore_user_abort(true)` in order to prevent the script from ending when user goes somewhere else.
- I don't get any execution runtime errors, or any errors at all... In the client side I get a GET error message to the script after 15 minutes, which is actually the second execution try. It's still running and socket is still delivering data, though it appears the script has ended.
- *There are no two separated requests*

I'm not sure what could be the problem of it, hopefully one of the masters here could hint with a clue?

Much thanks!

Comment: How do you know that script, as you said, re-executes?

Comment: Because it multiplies all the scripts activities at the moment of the re-execution

Comment: Eventually I kill the second execution with a token as mentioned, so with the same request I actually get the second execution message that it was trying to rerun and died...

Comment: Which SAPI are you using?

Comment: Could it be simply kinda bug in script? Does it use `fork` or other dirty things? Did you check that it's really being run twice with something like `ps aux | grep my_script.php`? Some code also will help.

Comment: @Shay Behind Apache?

Comment: @ksimka I would love to post some code but I cannot, I could check with the linux command you have mentioned, but I definitely see that it runs twice and I wish there was a recall to the function at some point but there isn't :)

Comment: @Dencker I'm not sure how to get that data.. :\

Comment: @Shay which webserver are you using? Try to run `curl -sSI http://url.to/yourfile.php | grep Server:` from a terminal.

Comment: @Dencker Apache obviously, just not sure what is behind. :)

Comment: That's not obvious ;) I'm suspecting a timeout. Maybe [`FcgidBusyTimeout`](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidbusytimeout)?

Comment: @Dencker hehe thanks :) I thought of Apache timeout as well, could it actually be timeout for apache connection but then reruns because the php function has the ignore_user_abort(true) that prevents it from being killed? That's my latest suspicion.. I will check it out! :)

Comment: @Shay Apache can still kill a PHP process. `ignore_user_abort()` will just make PHP to continue executing the script if an user aborts a HTTP request.